# electron Cant find module remote in the renderer process

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I recently upgraded to electron v1.3 from 0.37 and get Cannot find module 'remote' in the renderer process.

Been combing through the docs and haven't been able to come up with much

here's a part of my code

**RENDERER JS FILE**

```
var remote = require('electron').remote;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
const session = remote.require('electron').session; //i'm trying to use the session module here
var app = remote.require('electron').app; //and here too
```

**MAIN JS PROCESS**

```
const {app} = require('electron')
var fs = require('fs');
const {ipcMain} = require('electron')
const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const {session} = require('electron')
const {dialog} = require('electron')
```

Comment: can you past the stack trace error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with this code

```
const app = require('electron').remote.app
```

And in your Main process you can do this :

```
const {app, ipcMain, BrowserWindow, session, dialog} = require('electron')
var fs = require('fs');
```

Comment: Hi MaximeF, i still get the same error even after removing the remote module in the renderer process.

Answer (score 3):

On your renderer process you can invoke your variables like this:

```
var remote = require('electron').remote;
var session = require('electron).remote.session;  

var app = require('electron').app;
/*if the above line doesn't work try this*/
var app = require('electron').remote.app;

var ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
```

And in your main.js can use this

```
const {ipcMain, dialog, session, app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
var fs = require('fs');
```